# UIButton text not staying changing

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uibutton

**I am developing a simple iPhone app in Swift**

I have a custom`UITableViewCell`. In the cell I have a normal `UIButton` with text of "Hello World".

In my code for the custom cell, I have the following function:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if likeButton.titleLabel?.text == "Hello World" {

        likeButton.titleLabel?.text = "Hi!"

    }

}
```

When I tap the`UIButton`, the text of the`UIButton` changes to "Hi!" for just a split second! And then it quickly changes back to "Hello World"...is there any way to fix that?

Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UIButtons's` `setTitle: forState:` rather than setting text on `titleLabel` of button. For Instance-

Initial set up

```
likeButton.setTitle("Hello World", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

On click set up-

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if likeButton.titleLabel?.text == "Hello World" {
        likeButton.setTitle("Hi!", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
likeButton.setTitle("my text here", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Use this code

Answer (score 0):

Do Something like this :

@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    likeButton.setTitle("Hi!", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

it works here, hope also work there, set your default value-

```
yourButton.setTitle("Hello", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

when you tapped your button set this

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

if yourButton.titleLabel?.text == "Hello " {
    yourButton.setTitle("Max", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

}